# How to change the width and height of jQuery Skitter Slideshow?

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I 'd tried to change the width and height of jquery skitter slideshow. It's default size is width 800px and height 300px. I need width 960px and height 330px. My customized size appears only then when I click to next button. I'll be thankful if anyone could sort out my problem.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.box_skitter_large').skitter({
             theme: 'clean',
             numbers_align: 'center',
             progressbar: true, 
             dots: true, 
             preview: true
         });
     });
 </script>

 <div class="box_skitter box_skitter_large">
     <ul>
         <li> <img src="img/example/001.jpg" width="960px" height="330px" class="circles" /> </li>
         <li> <img src="img/example/002.jpg" width="960px" height="330px" class="circlesInside" /> </li>
         <li> <img src="img/example/003.jpg" width="960px" height="330px" class="circlesRotate" /> </li>
         <li> <img src="img/example/004.jpg" width="960px" height="330px" class="cubeShow" /> </li> 
     </ul>
 </div>
```

## CSS

```
 .box_skitter { position: relative; width: 960px;   height: 330px;  background: #FFFFFF;}
 .box_skitter img { max-width: none;} .box_skitter ul { display: none;}
 .box_skitter .container_skitter {  overflow: hidden;   position: relative;}
 .box_skitter .image {  overflow: hidden;}
 .box_skitter .image img {  display: none;}
 .box_skitter .box_clone {  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;    width: 100px;   display: none;  z-index: 220;}
 .box_skitter .box_clone img {  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;    z-index: 20;}
 .box_skitter .prev_button {    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 35px; z-index: 152; width: 42px; height: 42px;  overflow: hidden; text-indent: -9999em; margin-top: -25px; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; -moz-transition: all 0.2s; transition: all 0.2s;}
 .box_skitter .next_button {    position: absolute; top: 50%;   right: 35px;    z-index: 152;   width: 42px;    height: 42px;   overflow: hidden;   text-indent: -9999em;   margin-top: -25px;  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;   -moz-transition: all 0.2s;  transition: all 0.2s;}
 .box_skitter .prev_button:hover, .box_skitter .next_button:hover { opacity: 0.5 !important;}
 .box_skitter_large {   width: 960px;   height: 330px border_box 0px;}
 .box_skitter_small {   width: 100px;   height: 100px;}
```

Comment: is there anyone to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container_skitter {
    width:1132px;
    height:357px;
}

.box_skitter {
    width:1132px;
    height:357px;
}

.box_skitter img {
    width: 1132px;
    height:357px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.box_skitter {
  heitgh: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

block .box_skitter adapted adjustment automatically (in my case the height unit became 173px)